# conversion of format in python

Tags: python-2.7, formatting

I have data like following

```
>P1;gi|467971|gb|AA3.1|

-MASLAALLPLLALLVLCRLDPAQA
QAEPGAGG-LQELALQ---KRGIVE
QCCTSICSLYQLEN---
*
>P1;gi|307072|gb|AAA59179.1|

-MALWMRLLPLLALLALWGPDPAAA
FPK-TR-EAPGAGS-LEGSLQ--KRE
QCCTSICSLYQLENYCN
*
>P1;gi|387059|gb|AAA31.1|

-MALVLALLALWNTNQAFVS-RHLC
FYIPK-DRREG-LQLQ---KRGIVD
QCCTGTCTRHQLQS---
*
```

In python, how can i convert these to data looking like following

-MASLAALLPLLALLVLCRLDPAQAQAEPGAGG-LQELALQ---KRGIVEQCCTSICSLYQLEN---,-  MALWMRLLPLLALLALWGPDPAAAFPK-TR-EAPGAGS-LEGSLQ--KREQCCTSICSLYQLENYCN,-MALVLALLALWNTNQAFVS-RHLCFYIPK-DRREG-LQLQ---KRGIVDQCCTGTCTRHQLQS---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A kludgy way where `data` is your "string":

```
>>> lines = data.replace('*', ',').splitlines()
>>> ''.join(line for line in lines if line and not line.startswith('>')).rstrip(',')
```

> '-MASLAALLPLLALLVLCRLDPAQAQAEPGAGG-LQELALQ---KRGIVEQCCTSICSLYQLEN---,-MALWMRLLPLLALLALWGPDPAAAFPK-TR-EAPGAGS-LEGSLQ--KREQCCTSICSLYQLENYCN,-MALVLALLALWNTNQAFVS-RHLCFYIPK-DRREG-LQLQ---KRGIVDQCCTGTCTRHQLQS---'

Comment: this is amazing.within two lines, i can't believe.Thank you very much@Jon Clements

Answer (score 0):

Considering the data is available in the file1.txt then you can use this piece of code:

```
file_handle = open(r'C:\Users\kvivek\Desktop\file1.txt', 'r')
fileContent = file_handle.readlines()
file_handle.close()

output = ''
for line in fileContent:
    if ">P1;gi" in line:
        continue
    x = ''.join(line.strip())
    output = output + x

// replace all * with comma and then use strip function used to remove the last comma
finalOutput = output.replace("*",",").rstrip(',')
print finalOutput
```